# How to get OS version number?

Tags: windows-phone-7, operating-system, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the current OS version of Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340908/how-to-get-the-current-os-version-of-windows-phone)

How to get installed OS version number on the Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
Environment.OSVersion.Version
```

Comment: Apparently not available on windows 10 UWP/iot-core. ?

Answer (score 2):

System.Environment.OSVersion should do the trick: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx