# How to get the current OS version of Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need to get the current OS version of a Windows phone. That is, if it is Windows Phone 7.0 or  7.1, so that I have to write code supporting for both OS versions. I have to run my app in both 7.0 and 7.1.

Answer (score 13):

you can get the OS Major and minor version of the phone OS through this following statement

```
temp = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
temp = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
```

in both the WP 7.0 and 7.1 major version is 7
but Minor version differs. For Wp7.0 it is 0 and 7.1 it is 10

Answer (score 3):

Use [`System.Environment.OSVersion.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: but if is use this code i get the output as Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600.0 but i want to get the os version.is there any code to get the out put as 7.0 or 7.1 ?