# check OS version windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get OS version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242032/how-to-get-os-version-number)
>   [How to get the current OS version of Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340908/how-to-get-the-current-os-version-of-windows-phone)

I have a question:

is it possible to check a wp7 device's OS version? I want to know, because I'm creating a sort of distributing app, where users, based on their OS version, and privileges can connect to the BETA marketplace and download certain apps from there. So if someone doesn't have a compatable OS, they get a message notifying them of this and locking certain apps. Is this even possible, because the OS version is not found in the Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus class, only firm- and hardware versions. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also get the Windows Phone Operating System Version number from Environment.OSVersion.

```
string OSVersion = Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Saurabh's answer - you can find a useful information such as an example and usage information about the API here:

[Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: @GeekPeek Press the "Other Versions" tab at the top of the page to be Silverlight instead of .NET Framework 4. Then you'll see that it is indeed support on the Windows Phone OS. I've edited my link to make it specific in this case.